# Don't Understand why this does not work input string

Tags: java, string, input, joptionpane

Sorry guys I just have a quick question. I am trying to figure out why program won't print out "Your item is a moose" when the user enters animal at the first prompt and then puts yes at the second prompt. Any help would be great thanks

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String Answer1;
    String Answer2;

    // Read in how much cash the user has
    Answer1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Question 1: Is it an animal, vegetable, or mineral");
    Answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Question 2: Is it bigger than a breadbox");


    if (Answer1 == "animal" && Answer2 == "yes") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your item is: A Moose");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Look at the Javadoc for String.equals.  You can't compare string contents using the == operator.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you wouldn't compare strings with the double equal symbol, it just for integers. You would do it using the method `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings doesn't matter if there are in Upper Case or not.

```
if (Answer1 == "animal" && Answer2 == "yes") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your item is: A Moose");
    }
```

So, in your case, you can use `equals`

```
if (Answer1.equals("animal") && Answer2.equals("yes")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your item is: A Moose");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the `==` conditional operator for `String`s in Java because they are `Object`s.

When you use `==` for Objects, it compares the value of their address instead of the actual value.

Instead use

```
Answer1.equals("animal") && Answer2.equals("yes")
```

in your condition.